# What settings should I use to replicate this "lava" effect using flip fluids?

Tags: shaders, physics, fluid-simulation, custom-attributes

https://www.youtube.com/shorts/p3OhspLdgdU

I want to replicate the emission strength fading according to speed like in the video. Additionally, I am trying to figure out how to go about having the fluid fold and layer on top of itself like in the video. Tried messing around with viscosity, vorticity, speed, sheeting, and surface tension but to no avail.

Another important detail is how the surface textures "flow" with the lava and aren't static in 3D space. It molds with the fluid as it droops down the surface and onto itself as well.

Thank you for any advice!

[image]